# Is there a CKEditor PHP drop-in for editing a site (psuedo cms)?

Tags: php, html, content-management-system, ckeditor

I like CKEditor and my server uses PHP.   I want to use CKEditor to edit the static HTML pages.  Is there something that I can drop in that will give me a file browser and let me click a file and edit in CKEditor and save?   Image upload would be nice but optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got new information... you could use [ckfinder](http://ckfinder.com/) to select your files. I haven't looked closely at this but I think you would them be able to put the results into the editor and find some way to save it back, but it all sounds Like a bad idea to develop pages through ckeditor but that's just me

**EDIT:** I had edited may answer after finding out that you can integrate ckfinder with ckeditor

check out this [integration documantaion](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder/Developers_Guide/PHP/CKEditor_Integration)  I think that'll help you

Comment: Did you find any general instructions on how to do it?
I ended up using Drupal with WYSIWYG module and CKEDITOR - it is a pretty easy setup, BUT, it would sure be nice if I could have something that was plain old static HTML pages but I could drop in CKEDITOR to edit those pages -- easily.

Comment: thanks, that looks good.
Do you happen to know if CKFinder can be used freely (at least for personal use)?   I saw somewhere that CKEditor is open/free, but CKFinder is not?